# AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS called after a phone call in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to pause media player when the phone rings. I use the sample code from android site. It's like this;

```
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // resume playback
            if (mMediaPlayer != null && !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            }

            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and
            // release media player
            stopMediaPlayer();
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
            // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
            // is likely to resume
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
            // at an attenuated level
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
        }
    }
```

When the phone rings AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT is sent; which is OK. And when the call ends the AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN is sent and the player continue to play; which is also OK. But right after sending AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN, AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS is sent. Have any ideas why it is losing audio focus? Thx in advance.

Comment: I added a bounty to this question because I've seen the same thing sometimes. Or I get a loop of AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN=>AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS=>AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN=>AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS=>AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN=>AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS=>... etc.

Comment: What device do you use (test with the emulator)? Does it have google music? Can you verify that it works with another music player (e.g. google music)? Append a logcat. There can be interesting things there. Could there be any other (old) music app that listens for the call to end and "steals" the focus?

Comment: I also have the same problem: my device is Galaxy Note N7000 - android 4.0.3. And one more thing: after AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS is fired, the listener never get called again !

Answer (score 3):

Two things to check: 
1) Do you have a play button for instance, that when clicked, requests focus and starts playback? I had a problem once that they played a "tick" sound to provide feedback of a click.  They would take audio focus away from my app when that happened. In your XML set this value to false for all your buttons in that activity:

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled = 'false'
```

2) Check for the installation of other media player apps that also request focus. Are they requesting focus right after losing it? If so there's not much you can do about this other than warn your users not to install this app.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it will help somebody.
I had this issue when in project wasn't using directly MediaPlayer but through VideoView.
It has following code while opening the file

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

So as you open the file it gains audio focus and listener that is set before gets fired with focusChange `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`.