# Will this method be called? (Still needs an accepted answer...See details in answer)

Tags: java, android, string, android-activity, optimization

### TL;DR:

**Does `onPause` method get called during phone call?**

I have a permission to READ_PHONE_STATE which I don't want. So, does the onPause method get called on a phone call, so that I can mute my apps audio there?

```
private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (doesUserHavePermission()) {


            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I made that mutes audio for phone call
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I made that mutes audio for phone call
            }
        }
    }

};
```

This requires this permission:

[image]

Which I want to get rid of. So do I have to explicitly listen for a call? Or can I just mute in the onPause() ?

Here is my app, you can see the permission requests on an attempt to download:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.culybrace.ruchir.buttonsmasher&hl=en

Comment: onPause get called as soon as the activity/fragment goes into the background, so if the phone call app has a layout, I guess it will work

Comment: @RuchirBaronia why you don't want READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Comment: create a background service to check your phone current state....if phone is ringing or activated then mute your audio

Comment: @HetalUpadhyay ...checking current state requires that permission...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, It depends on phones.
there are 2 cases.
1. when ring comes -> new Call Activity starts.
  : In this case onPause is called because new Activity is over your app.
2. when ring comes -> ring window shows over the app.(not activity)
  : In this case no Activity call back is called. and user can use the app as before the ring called.

you may can use AudioManager without permission, check this out
[AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS called after a phone call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334110/audiofocus-loss-called-after-phone-in-android)

Comment: I checked out the link, but it was of no help...Do you know how I can check for an incoming phone call?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know will the method be called, you can simply just use the debug function by press `Shift + F9` while you got your emulator / external device plug in, drop the debugger on the line which you would like to see if it's run or not, press `F9` to move to the next debugger, press `F8` to move to the next line.

Comment: Okay, great advice. how do I know if there is an incoming phone call?